# Django login(request, user) return none

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-views

When I submit a valid username and password with login form it's redirected to same page with next URL and User not logged in.
I have no idea why this is happening. :(

**Views.py code**

```
def sign_in(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.user_cache is not None:
                user = form.user_cache
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    next_url = request.GET.get('next')
                    if next_url:
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(next_url)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_dashboard_url/')
            else:
                messages.add_message(
                    request, messages.ERROR,
                    "Username or password is incorrect."
                )

    return render(request, 'sign_in.html', {'form': form})
```

**HTML Form**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
                <form method="POST" class="form"> 
                    {% crispy form %}
                    <div class="form-action mb-3">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded btn-login">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: you have used multiple if block, check every else point(print out in each else).

Comment: Please, give AuthenticationForm() code.

Comment: @MuminurRahman AuthenticationForm() is Django's Builtin form

Answer (score 0):

```
delete this:
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.user_cache is not None:
                user = form.user_cache
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    next_url = request.GET.get('next')
                    if next_url:
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(next_url)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_dashboard_url/')

replace with:
if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid() and form.user_cache is not None:
                user = form.user_cache
                if user.is_active:
                     login(request, user)
                     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('appname:viewname'))
```

> be sure that you include a urls.py in your app and in that include a app_name and make a url to
>   your view so probaly would look something like this:

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    app_name = 'finance'
urlpatterns = [
    path('user_dashboard_url/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),]

    reverse would be: reverse('finance:dashboard'), given the example of the urls.py

    add to your view:

    @login_required < this wil make sure that if a user is not valid its not possible to use this view ;)
    def view_name(request):
          blablablabla
```

>

```
     btw, go and use the django authentication that wil save you alot of headache.
>     [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/][1]


  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `request` to `AuthenticationForm()`. That is, use `AuthenticationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)`.